# Calling CreateFile using JNA gives UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'CreateFile': The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: java, jna, createfile

I'm trying to call Win32's `CreateFile` function on Windows 7 using JNA with the aim being to do a Java implementation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409325/check-if-a-file-is-open-from-another-process/411672#411672) to checking if a file is in use by another process.

The code I have so far is:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.examples.win32.Kernel32;

public class CreateFileExample {

    static int GENERIC_ACCESS = 268435456;
    static int EXCLUSIVE_ACCESS = 0;
    static int OPEN_EXISTING = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kernel32 kernel32 = 
            (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);
        kernel32.CreateFile("c:\\file.txt", GENERIC_ACCESS, EXCLUSIVE_ACCESS,
            null, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, null);
    }
}
```

However, running this raises the exception:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'CreateFile': The specified procedure could not be found.`

If I change `"kernel32"` in the `loadLibrary` call to something invalid then instead I get `The specified module could not be found` so this suggests that the DLL is being found correctly from the library path, but there's something wrong with the way I'm calling `CreateFile`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

---

`CreateFile` is defined in `com.sun.jna.examples.win32.Kernel32` as:

```
public abstract com.sun.jna.examples.win32.W32API.HANDLE CreateFile(
    java.lang.String arg0,
    int arg1,
    int arg2,
    com.sun.jna.examples.win32.Kernel32.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES arg3,
    int arg4,
    int arg5,
    com.sun.jna.examples.win32.W32API.HANDLE arg6);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows API has ASCII and Unicode versions of functions (`CreateFileA` and `CreateFileW`), thus you need to specify which one do you want when calling `loadLibrary()`:

```
Kernel32 kernel32 = 
    (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
```

Also, actually you don't need to call `loadLibrary()` manually:

```
Kernel32 kernel32 = Kernel32.INSTANCE;
```

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for the tip on not needing the manual `loadLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

try writing function like this

```
HANDLE hDeviceUSB = Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateFile(szCom,
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                    0,              
                    null,          
                    OPEN_EXISTING,  
                    0,              
                    null);
```